# CONSULTA SQL EN MODELO DE LARAVEL

Tags: sql, laravel

Alguien podria ayudarme o decirme si puedo poner una consulta sql pura en un modelo de laravel, esto porque me gustaria no tner mucho codigo en mi controlador, ya que es una consulta demasiado grande y por eso me gustaria tenerla en un modelo en laravel, En dado caso que no se pueda me gustaria como acoplarla en laravel.., si preguntan porque no creo una vista en SQL es porque no me tienen permitido crear vistas en la base de datos, ya que los que realizaron el software es una empresa de terceros

```
SELECT     
M.FECHA, 
M.MONEDA,
M.NUMCTA,
M.CONCEPTO,
M.IMPORTE, 
M.IMPORTEEXT, 
M.TC,
F.FACTURA, 
F.DENOMINACION_SOCIAL, 
F.SUBTOTAL,
F.TOTAL, 
F.APLICADO, 
F.SALDO, 
F.PEDIDO_ANTICIPO,
CONCAT(V.NOMBRE, ' ',V.APELLIDOPATERNO,' ',V.APELLIDOMATERNO) AS VENDEDOR,
CASE M.NUMCTA
--CTA. VENTAS
when 41010100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 41010100200 then 'COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO'
when 41010100300 then 'EQUIPO ELECTRICO'
when 21750100100 then 'ANTICIPO'
when 41010100400 then 'ARRANCADORES BENSHAW'
when 41010100500 then 'MONTACARGAS'
when 41010100600 then 'FRENOPARTES'
when 41010100700 then 'ARRENDAMIENTOS DE LOCALES'
when 41010100800 then 'CORTADORA DE PISOS'
when 41010100900 then 'GENERADODRES ELECTRICOS'
when 41010199900 then 'DEPOSITIOS NO IDENTIFICADOS'
when 11200100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 21750100200 then 'ANTICIPO'
--CTA. ANTICIPOS
when 41020100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 41020100200 then 'COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO'
 when 41020100300 then 'MONTACARGAS'
 --CTA. BONIF.ANT
when 41020200100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 41020200200 then 'COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO'
when 41020200300 then 'MONTACARGAS'
-- CTA. DEVOLUCIONES
when 42010100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 42010100200 then 'COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO'
when 42010100300 then 'EQUIPO ELECTRICO'
when 42010100400 then 'ARRANCADORES BENSHAW'
when 42010100500 then 'MONTACARGAS'
when 42010100600 then 'FRENOPARTES'
when 42010100800 then 'CORTADORA DE PISOS'
when 42010100900 then 'GENERADORES ELECTRICOS'
--CTA. REBAJAS
when 42020100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 42020100200 then 'COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO'
when 42020100300 then 'EQUIPO ELECTRICO'
when 42020100400 then 'ARRANCADORES BENSHAW'
when 42020100500 then 'MONTACARGAS'
when 42020100600 then 'FRENOPARTES'
when 42020100700 then 'ARRENDAMIENTO DE LOCALES'
when 42020100800 then 'CORTADORA DE PISOS'
when 42020100900 then 'GENERADORES ELECTRICOS'
when 42020100900 then 'DEPOSITOS NO IDENTIFICADOS'
--CTA. BONIF. VTA
when 42030100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
when 42030100200 then 'COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO'
when 42030100300 then 'EQUIPO ELECTRICO'
when 42030100400 then 'ARRANCADORES BENSHAW'
when 42030100500 then 'MONTACARGAS'
when  42030100600 then 'FRENOPARTES'
when 42030100700 then 'ARRENDAMIENTOS DE LOCALES'
-- CTA. SERVICIOS 
when 41030100100 then 'TRANSFORMADORES'
END As FAMILIA,
CASE 
--TRANSFORMADORES--
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%MONOFASICO%PEDESTAL%')     then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%MONOFASICO%PEDESTA%')     then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%POSTE%CAP%')     then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%SECO%CA%')       then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%SECO%75K%')      then  0.01
-- when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%POSTE%CAP%')     then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%MONOFASICO%SECO%C%')       then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%MONOFASICO%POSTE%CO%')     then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%MONOFASICO%POSTE%')        then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%POSTE%C%')       then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%PEDESTAL%')      then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%TRIFASICO%POSTE%15%')      then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%CONTROL%1F%5000VA%44%')    then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%FERRELECTRICA%INDUSTRIAL%S.A.%DE%C.V%')  then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%INGENIERIA%ELECTRICA%PROYECTOS%DE%ENER%')then  0.005
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%SYDEC%EQUIPOS%INDUSTRIALES%S.A%DE%C.V%') then  0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%EMPAQUE%ACRILICO%NITRILO%80%') then   0.02
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%EMPAQUE%ACRILICO%NORMAL%80%') then   0.01
when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TRANSFORMADOR%MONOFASICO%CONVENCIONAL%') then   0.005
--COMPONENTES PARA TRAFO
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%41010100200%') then   0.02
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%41020100200%') then   0.02
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%41020200200%') then   0.02
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%42010100200%') then   0.02
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%42020100200%') then   0.02
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%42030100200%') then   0.02
--EQUIPO ELECTRICO
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%BUS%4%VIAS%15%/%25%KV%600%A%25-DJ6F4SS%')   then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%BUS%4%VIAS%15%KV%200%A%15-LJ200F4SS%C%')    then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CODO%SENCILLO%15%KV%200%A%1%/%0%15-LE200%') then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CODO%SENCILLO%15%KV%200%A%3%/%0%15-LE200%') then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%FUSIBLE%PARA%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%15%KV%30%')  then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%BUS%3%VIAS%15%KV%200%A%15-LJ200F3SS%CH%')   then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ADAPTADOR%A%TIERRA%35%KV%3/0%15%KV%50%')    then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%FUSIBLE%PARA%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%15%KV%6%')   then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%APARTARRAYOS%TIPO%DISTRIBUCION%CONTAMIN%')  then   0.02
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%15%KV%200%A%1/0%15-L%')   then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%15%KV%200%A%3/0%15-L%')   then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ADAPTADOR%A%TIERRA%15%KV%1/0%SADP-B%C%')    then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ADAPTADOR%A%TIERRA%15%KV%3/0%25%KV%1%/')    then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%INSERTO%SENCILLO%15%KV%200%A%15-LBI200%')   then   0.0
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CONO%DE%ALIVIO%CONTRACTIL%EN%FRIO%15%KV')   then   0.02
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%FUSIBLE%PARA%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%15%KV%6%')   then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CODO%SENCILLO%35%KV%200%A%1/0%35-LE200')    then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%INSERTO%DOBLE%15%KV%200%A%15-LFTIR%CH%')    then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CORTACIRCULITOS%FUSIBLE%15-25%KV%200%A%')   then   0.03
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%FUSIBLE%PARA%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%8.3%KV%1%')  then   0.02
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ADAPTADOR%A%TIERRA%25%KV%500%KCM-15%K%')    then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ADAPTADOR%A%TIERRA%35%KV%1/0%SADP-E%C%')    then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%FUSIBLE%PARA%CODO%PORTAFUSIBLE%15%KV%8%')   then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%DESCANSO%SENCILLO%15%KV%200%A%161SOP%')     then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%TAPON%AISLADO%PARA%INSERTO%15%KV%200%A%')   then   0.01
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%BUS%MIXTO%3%VIAS%15/25%KV%200/600%A%MP%')   then   0.015
 when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%CODO%CON%APARTARRAYOS%15%KV%15-LEA10%')     then   0.01

 --Anticipos 
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(18)%DESCAN%S%')     then   0.02
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(9)%INDICADOR%D%')   then   0.02
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(2)%TRANSFORMAD%')   then   0.01
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(72)%DESCANSO%S%')   then   0.02
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(4)%BOQUILLA%BT%')   then   0.02
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(72)%INDICADOR%')    then   0.02
  when (M.CONCEPTO LIKE '%ANTICIPO%EN%LA%COMPRA%DE%(1)%TRANSFORMAD%')  then   0.005
  ELSE .01
 --else .015
END As PORCENTAJE,
--ANTICIPO 
case 
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%21750100100%')  then F.APLICADO/1.16/F.SUBTOTAL
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%21750100200%')  then F.APLICADO/1.16/F.SUBTOTAL
END As  ANTICIPO,
--CALCULAR ANTICIPO 
case  
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%21750100100%')  then F.PEDIDO_ANTICIPO
when (M.NUMCTA LIKE '%21750100200%')  then F.PEDIDO_ANTICIPO
else M.IMPORTE
END AS VENTA
FROM MOVIMIENTOS AS M 
FULL OUTER JOIN v_IGQ_Reporte_Vendedores_2 AS F ON M.FOLIO=F.FACTURA
INNER JOIN VENDEDORES AS V ON F.VENDEDOR = V.VENDEDOR
WHERE
M.FECHA>'20191231' AND
M.TIPOPOL =  'VTA' AND
F.VENDEDOR = '15' AND
(M.NUMCTA = 41010100100  OR
M.NUMCTA = 41010100200  OR
M.NUMCTA = 41010100300  OR
M.NUMCTA = 41020100100  OR
M.NUMCTA = 41020100200 OR
M.NUMCTA = 21750100100)
ORDER BY M.FOLIO DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$variable = Input::get("variable");

$results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = :variable"), array(
   'variable' => $variable
));
```